# Error when compiling a basic web service client in Java

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-ee-6

I am trying to run the following java EE web service client for days:

```
package servclient;

import tuto.helloserv.HelloService;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;

public class ServClient {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:1991/HelloService/HelloService?wsdl")
    public static HelloService helloServ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(webCall("world"));
    }

    private static String webCall(java.lang.String arg0) {
        tuto.helloserv.Hello port = helloServ.getHelloPort();
        return port.webCall(arg0);
    }
}
```

Yet I get the following error on netbeans even though the web service url is true;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at servclient.ServClient.webCall(ServClient.java:25)
    at servclient.ServClient.main(ServClient.java:21)
C:\Users\DevShop\Documents\wapps\ServClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1329: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\DevShop\Documents\wapps\ServClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:981: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I run java 1.8.0_261 on my machine and I cant find any clear solution to this in any of the known forums.

Comment: Did you generate the service client code by wsimport or which tool?

Comment: @HatemMohamed This example is taken from java EE 7 offocial documentaion. Here is the link https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxws001.htm

Comment: @HatemMohamed Yes I imported the service with wsimport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation `@WebServiceRef` is used with java EE not SE

So in order to use the service from java SE you need to generate the client for the service from the wsdl

see this tutorial about wsimport : [Java Brains wsimport tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwXsrcJyjiI)
And this one too will help : [Calling the service from generated client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFlDdb65w3U&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZTYpk_1DOowOGWJMIH5T39&index=5&t=0s)

Comment: I already did that sir. This is the netbeans output : init:
wsimport-init:
wsimport-client-HelloService ...

Comment: but i see you are using 
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:1991/HelloService/HelloService?wsdl")
    public static HelloService helloServ;

Comment: And then you are trying to call the helloServ.getHelloPort and helloServ will be null at this point

Comment: so instead of using the annotation just instantiate the service from the client code generated

Comment: Yes I ll do that I think this is a bug in netbeans